# Хочу вывести только записи ipv4 или ipv6

Tags: linux

Работаю с командной строкой линукса, в руководстве host указано, что для вывода записей вида ipv4 нужно указывать параметр -4, а для записей ipv6 соответственно -6, но терминал почему-то выдает иное
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опции `-4` и `-6` указывают способ обращения к DNS-серверу, а не вывод результата. Для вывода только определённого типа записей используйте `-t a` и `-t aaaa` соответственно